# Import vendor class in CakePHP 3 without require

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do I use an `Vendor` class without use:

```
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');
use ImageTool;
```

> Note: this class that I want use don't have autoload (not access with composer) and namespace is only a single class.

and use the **CakePHP 3** pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your local `composer.json` autoloader to use either `classmap`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "./vendor/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component"
    ]
}
```

**https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap**

or `files` autoloading for your vendor library

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "./vendor/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component/ImageTool.php"
    ]
}
```

**https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files**

and then re-dump the autoloader

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload**

**Note** that `files` autoloading will always load the defined files on every request, and not just when a specific class is being accessed!